# Why is the indefinite article used in "as a last resort"?

Tags: articles

Someone asked me this question today and I didn't really know how to answer the question.  When something is *last*, the definite article should precede it because there's only one last place.

Comment: A final course of action, used only when all else has failed:
asking them to leave the school should be a last resort
[AS MODIFIER]: a

Comment: @V.V. A final course of action becomes the final course of action when applied to a situation.  Asking them to leave the school should be the last resort...

Comment: 1 Getting a last place medal at the school's field day would bum me out. I'm glad they don't award them. 2 I can tell you that a last place I want to be when the world ends is at a strip joint. Another (last place) would be at a McDonald's.

Comment: What if it's just an idiomatic expression?

Comment: If your first course of action succeeds, then technically it was your "last resort", since you didn't need any of the other ones...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Not exactly. In that case, it was last, but not necessarily a resort, since that implies a course of action undesirable by comparison to other options or outcomes.

Comment: You use the indefinite article because you're unsure whether it will work or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you [Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20a%20last%20resort&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20a%20last%20resort%3B%2Cc0) the phrase you'll find at least a couple of dictionaries that define "[as a last resort](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/it/definizione/inglese/last-resort)" "as the last choice," while others offer "in the last resort" as an alternative phrase. Thus, I believe it is simply an idiom in widespread use, and there is no sound grammatical reason to use the indefinite article.

(ODO)

Comment: What if I wanna say: **'as a second to last resort'** or **'as a second to the last resort'** or **'as the second to last resort'** or **'as the second to a last resort'**. Which one would be better?

Comment: The penultimate resort

Comment: **'as a penultimate resort'** or **'as the penultimate resort'**?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "second-to-last resort." See Rathony's answer (and Ben's) for more insight.

Comment: Agreed.  Seems like people are overthinking this.  It's a colloquialism, grammar does not apply.  The last resort would be equally "correct," it's just less popular.

Answer (score 26):

The question said:

> When something is last, the definite article should precede it because there's *only one* last place.

But that's not the case here.

These are hypotheticals, as they have not yet happened. So there can be more than one *possible* last resort.

If you have a choice of mutually exclusive last resorts, then each is *a* last resort, while still being last. This will be the case if only one of a choice of last resorts is possible.

- As a last resort you could scuttle the ship by firing the magazine.
- Or you could ram the enemy
- Or you could surrender

But you cannot do all three as they exclude each other, so any will be ***the*** last resort if it is used, but whilst under consideration, each is ***a*** last resort.

Comment: No; I think that 'as a last resort' and 'in the last resort' are synonymous, at least nowadays.

Comment: +1 This is the case. It is similar to taking about a TV show called Fl&yvv÷¥S. We can talk about *a first season*, *another season*, *a second season*, ***a last season*** of Fl&yvv÷¥S before any or all are ever made. There's a first time for everything, and there's **a last time** for everything.

Comment: @GoDucks Can you explain the difference in the [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+last+time%2C+the+last+time&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20last%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20last%20time%3B%2Cc0) about the last time and a last time? I don't think you call the first episode, the first season "a first episode" or "a first season". They have different meanings.

Comment: This is the key perspective missing from the question. There can only be one last resort actually chosen but there are many choices of what that last resort might be.

Comment: This would be an interesting answer, if people used "a last resort" in this way. Nearly always when someone refers to something as a last resort, he or she means it to be the only last resort.  Also, when people refer to specific past actions as the final bail-out act, they use "a last resort" over "the last resort." [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+a+last+resort%2C+was+the+last+resort&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20a%20last%20resort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20the%20last%20resort%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Ngram, I like the note about 'specific past actions', as in, at the moment, it may have been 'the last resort', but now, with hindsight being 20/20, that  action was merely 'a last resort'.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Mark Hubbard's great answer, if there were numerous resorts that were used before **the** last resort, it would be correct to use *as the last resort*. The noun [**resort**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/resort) is a **mass noun** that takes an indefinite article **only** when it is used to mean:

> A course of action that is resorted to: '*her only resort is a private
>   operation*. '*Surgery is **a** last resort, though it sometimes is necessary*'

The second example sentence didn't use the definite article **the**. It is obvious that the noun resort is something that you "turn to and adopt (a course of action, especially **an extreme or undesirable one**) so as to **resolve a difficult situation**".

You don't resort to multiple resorts (extreme or undesirable courses of action). You resort to only **one** resort.

The indefinite article *a* in the idiom means **one single**:

> As **one single** last resort, she decided to undergo surgery.

The adjective [**last**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/last) usually requires the definite article, but there is an exception when it **doesn't** mean:

> Coming after all others in time or order, final: '*they caught the last bus*'.

A resort doesn't come after another resort and is not final. That's why the definite article is not necessary.

If you compare the idiom with [**as the last choice**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+a+last+resort), the distinction would be  clearer. You had multiple choices before you take the last choice, but you didn't have multiple resorts before you take **a** last resort.

**Note**: This is a broadly used idiom and sometimes an idiom can't be explained using a grammatical rule or dictionary definition. As some commented, it is as idiomatic as **in the last resort** and **as the last resort** and why one idiom uses **a** and the other **the** is difficult to explain.

Even thought the linked [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suicide+as+a+last+resort%2C+suicide+as+the+last+resort&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuicide%20as%20a%20last%20resort%3B%2Cc0) for "suicide as a last resort" and "suicide as the last resort" shows only "suicide as a last resort", if you Google them, you get 12,800 hits for the former and 28,000 hits for the latter.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: Could you please answer my question in Mark Hubbard's answer's comments then?

Comment: @haha I don't think you take two resorts as the noun clearly implies the choice that you have to take in an extremely difficult situation where you don't have any other choice but to take a last resort. That's why **as a last resort** became such an idiom, I think.

Answer (score 3):

"Last resort" refers to a course of action taken when all others fail or no others are available. "Last" in this circumstance refers to something along the lines of "this will definitely work, but may have bad side-effects," "if this doesn't work, nothing will," or "once we try this, we won't be able to try anything else." It implies a lack of desirability in the option. "Last resort" thus doesn't refer to a particular action, but a *class* of actions. Multiple last resorts for a single problem can exist.